# A dot in project name interpreted as namespace delimiter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a project that was working fine until now. Suddenly, when I did the standard "Rebuild->Start" chain of actions in Visual Studio 2015 the following error is raised in a non-modified file:

```
CS0234: The type or namespace 'Bar' does not exist in the namespace 'Foo'
        (are you missing an assembly reference?)

@using Foo.Bar.Models
```

My project's name is `Foo.Bar`. I'm wondering why suddenly the compiler threats the dot as a namespace delimiter while earlier it was OK that it's a part of the project's name.

I repeat: it happens in a file I didn't modify in quite some time now.

Also (since last time it was working) I didn't change any configuration by hand. Though, I may have done so accidentally through git (`git stash; git rebase; git stash pop`).

I kindly ask for your help.

**Update 1** 
I was making changes to references and installed libs but since last such operation the project was compiling and working.

Comment: You might not have modified this file but the namespace that Models is defined in could have changed.

Comment: @r-day  I didn't make any structural changes to the project itself, I was only adding content to the existing structure. Thanks anyway.

Comment: is it possible that you have a namespace collision? that you have more than one `Foo` namespace?

Comment: A dot in project name will be a namespace, I usually name my projects like that MyProject.Data.EntityFramewor, or MyProject.WPF. Don't use dots in project name so.

Comment: Try to Build -> Clean Solution, then Build -> Rebuild Solution

Comment: @Claies yes, I have more projects having name of the form `Foo.*`.   **Murilo**: Naming the project name is beyond my possibilities, I have to comply to existing work.   **Vlad Bezden**: I tried it a million times in all possible (and impossible) permutations

Comment: is that a "yes I have a namespace collision", or a "no, I can't have a namespace collision because other similar classes work"?  Honestly, this isn't something that we can walk you through troubleshooting in comments, especially with obfuscated names.

Comment: @Claies Sorry, I wanted to imply that I have not (should have not?) namespace collisions as it previously worked fine with many projects with the same prefix. (now I see it wasn't clear in my comment)

Comment: did `Foo.Bar` fail to compile for some reason?  can you try to only compile this `Foo.Bar` project?

Comment: the project `Foo.Bar` compiles. It's at runtime that there are problems. I set the `Copy Local` property of all references to `true` (so they are available at run time, I guess)